# Form of writing in a new file?

Tags: python, file

I was asked to write a program which takes a txt file which contains simple math exercises and inputs them into a new txt file with their answer
my code is the following:

```
import sys
import os.path

pathex=input("input exercises file path ")
pathsol=input("Input solutions file path ")
if not(os.path.exists(pathex)):
    print("exercises file does not exist in the inputted directory ")
    if not (os.path.exists(pathsol)):
        print("solutions file does not exist in the inputted directory")
    sys.exit()

with open(pathsol,'w') as solutions:
    with open(pathex,'r') as exercises:
        for line in exercises:
            list = line.rstrip('\n').split(' ')
            if list[1]=='+':
                solutions.write(line + '='+ str(int(list[0])+int(list[2])))
            if list[1]=='-':
                solutions.write(line + '='+ str(int(list[0])-int(list[2])))
            if list[1]=='/':
                solutions.write(line + '='+ str(int(list[0])//int(list[2])))
```

My exercises file is the following:

```
6 + 4
15 - 3
14 / 14
```

My solutions file is just a blank txt file.

The expected result is for the solutions file to contain:

```
6 + 4 = 10
15 - 3 = 12
14 / 14 = 1
```

Comment: Which problem are you having?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
We also expect you to make a reasonable attempt to trace and diagnose the problem.  You've shown no tracing output.  Insert a few useful `print` statements to track program and data flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here

```
import sys
import os.path
pathex=input("input exercises file path ")
pathsol=input("Input solutions file path ")
if not(os.path.exists(pathex)):
    print("exercises file does not exist in the inputted directory ")
    if not (os.path.exists(pathsol)):
        print("solutions file does not exist in the inputted directory")
    sys.exit()
math = open(pathex, "r")
math_sol = open(pathsol, "w+")

expressions = math.readlines()
for expression in expressions:
    symbols = expression.split()
    if symbols[1] == "+":
        math_sol.write(str(int(symbols[0]) + int(symbols[2])) + "\n")
    if symbols[1] == "-":
        math_sol.write(str(int(symbols[0]) - int(symbols[2]))+ "\n")
    if symbols[1] == "*":
        math_sol.write(str(int(symbols[0]) * int(symbols[2]))+ "\n")
    if symbols[1] == "/":
        math_sol.write(str(int(symbols[0]) / int(symbols[2]))+ "\n")
math_sol.close()
math.close()
```